# How to decompile [vb]script from exe created by iexpress

Tags: vbscript, iexpress

Is it possible to de-compile or extract [vb]script from iExpress created VBScript?

I have an `.exe` program that is zipped using iExpress  `VBScript`.

Is it possible to de-compile it to see the source?

Comment: IExpress extracts it to ipx000.tmp folder in the temp folder to run it. Type `%temp%` in Start Run (Winkey + R).

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly easy. Open CMD in the dir of the exe and type:

```
exename.exe /t:%cd% /c
```

The files should appear in your current dir.